# Customer analyzer in Azure search with tokenizer "keyword_v2" doesn't return results for search test containing space

Tags: lucene, azure-cognitive-search

I have a field called machineTag in Azure Search Index created with below details:

```
"analyzers": [
{
    "@odata.type": "#Microsoft.Azure.Search.CustomAnalyzer",
    "name": "SWMLuceneAlongWithCustomHyphenAnalyser",
    "tokenizer": "keyword_v2",
    "tokenFilters": [
        "lowercase"
    ],
    "charFilters": []
}
```

]

and the index is

```
    {
        "name": "machineTag",
        "type": "Edm.String",
        "searchable": true,
        "filterable": true,
        "retrievable": true,
        "sortable": true,
        "facetable": true,
        "key": false,
        "indexAnalyzer": null,
        "searchAnalyzer": null,
        "analyzer": "SWMLuceneAlongWithCustomHyphenAnalyser"
    }
```

Now, there is text in this field called "high Machine", but my query:

```
search=machineTag:/.*high\%20machine.*/&$count=true&$top=100&$skip=0&$filter=machineTag%20ne%20null&$queyType=full
```

doesn't return any results. Am I doing anything wrong here?

If I test the analyzer, it returned a result as shown below, and my understanding is that escaping space should return results:
Input Body:

```
  {
     "analyzer":"SWMLuceneAlongWithCustomHyphenAnalyser",
     "text": "high Machine"
  }
```

Response:

```
 {
    "@odata.context": "https://abcd/$metadata#Microsoft.Azure.Search.V2016_09_01.AnalyzeResult",


  "tokens": [
        {
            "token": "high machine",
            "startOffset": 0,
            "endOffset": 12,
            "position": 0
        }
    ]
}
```

Asking the question in another way, the field would contain text with space and * character. If the analyzer is wrong, please suggest..

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The query you specified works, you have a typo in the query parameter name. Replace *queyType* with *que**r**yType* :

```
search=machineTag:/.*high\%20machine.*/&$count=true&$top=100&$skip=0&$filter=machineTag%20ne%20null&queryType=full
```

Comment: Removing $ prefixes from search, queryType parameters resolved the issue. Here is the correct query, $count=true&$filter=machineTag ne null&search=machineTag:/.*tarun\ Machine.*/&queryType=full.. Thank you @Yahnoosh, i do no have enough points to mark your answer as correct :(